# Remove BitBucket integration with jira

Tags: bitbucket, jira

I have a project in Jira with BitBucket integration set up. I cloned the project and the BitBucket integration stays the same. I would like to cut it and set an integration with another BitBucket repository.

I know that must be a .git folder that was somehow copied, just wanted to hear your take on this matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the JIRA-Bitbucket integration is done on a global level, rather than on a per project basis. Unfortunately this means there is no way to remove the Bitbucket integration from your cloned project.

The integration works by looking for Issue Keys in commit messages and it will associate the commit with every issue that has that issue key regardless of project.

You can still add a new Bitbucket repository to the existing integration and it will pick up any commits in that new repo that matches an issue key.

Comment: Thanks a lot Gene. This was a great answer. I was a bit afraid that I could not explain well the issue. You got it. Thanks again. I'll pay forward your help.